# Git log missing latest commit

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-log

I **pushed a commit from my MacBook** into the master branch of a project, but **the commit doesn't appear on my Windows** laptop (`git log`), it only appears on my MacBook (`git log`) or on the Bitbucket web interface of the repo.

How is that possible?

Both git local repos are referring to the same branch (master), and to the same bitbucket repo (one is pointing to it via SSH, the other (Windows) via HTTPS).

Commit happened 40 minutes ago, so I doubt any delay is occuring here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. If any of the answers helped you, please accept it (check mark below the up-vote button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after a pull/fetch, a simple `git log` (which defaults to `git log master`) would not show the commit pushed.

Try `git log origin/master` (after at least a `git fetch`)

Comment: Running `git fetch` + `git log origin/master` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `git fetch` or `git pull` on the Windows laptop.

Git Log does not update automatically on every push to the origin repository.

`git fetch` will fetch the changes from the remote repo but won't merge them into your local repo, while `git pull` will fetch the changes and try to merge them into your local repo.

Here are some useful inks:

- [git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)
- [git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

Comment: `git fetch` made the origin/master branch not appear in the history anymore (suggesting my repo wasn't up-to-date that remote branch), but the latest commit still didn't appear in the history.

Comment: run `git status` to find out on which branch are you. Is it possible you are not on the master branch? If you are not on the master branch, you will have to run `git log origin/master` after fetch, as stated by @VonC in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59920380/2279082)

Comment: I was in my master branch already, as `git branch` had confirmed me. This is the only branch I have.

Comment: Is it possible that your local master branch was not tracking the master on origin?

Comment: Don't think so as I had only one branch and one remote, and it had always worked so far.

Comment: Well as long as you solved your issue using @VonC's answer, that is what's important